# how could I achieve click like element named data1 by selenium with python?

Tags: python, selenium

how could I find the element just like 'find_element_by'？

```js
<MAP name=Map>
<AREA onclick='parent.parent.menu.clickMenuHead(1,"data1")' onfocus=this.blur() href="#" shape=rect coords=321,17,481,47>
<AREA onclick='parent.parent.menu.clickMenuHead(2,"data2")' onfocus=this.blur() href="#" shape=rect coords=321,61,481,91>
<AREA onclick='parent.parent.menu.clickMenuHead(3,"data3")' onfocus=this.blur() href="#" shape=rect coords=321,105,481,135>
<AREA onclick='parent.parent.menu.clickMenuHead(4,"data4")' onfocus=this.blur() href="#" shape=rect coords=321,149,481,179>
<AREA onclick='parent.parent.menu.clickMenuHead(5,"data5")' onfocus=this.blur() href="#" shape=rect coords=321,193,481,223>
</MAP>
```

Comment: Could you explain your question bit more, and post code if you have written any

Comment: I 'd like to get the element with data1 to implement an operation like click the data1 on this page.

Answer (score 1):

data1_element= `driver.find_element_by_xpath("//MAP[@name='MAP']/@onclick='parent.parent.menu.clickMenuHead(1,"data1")']")`

or

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//MAP[@name='MAP']/AREA[1]")
```